# when to run python program as module using "-m"

Tags: python

Generally I run python program using

`python filename.py`

but I say, sometimes people run it like

`python -m filname`

What is the difference? where which to be used?

Comment: The latter works for libraries that are installed in your Python site packages directory, and not in your current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python allows the -m command line switch to allow modules to be executed using the python module namespace as scripts. A good example is the python debugger, pdb, which you can use to debug your scripts with

```
python -m pdb <filename>.py
```

See [PEP 338](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/)

For more info on [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)